# What is the difference between Facebook HTML and standard HTML5?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

Customer has hired me to make a simple Facebook page. As I have no experience with Facebook webpages, can you please appoint me to the wright resources for the following question:

**What is the difference between HTML5 as we know it and "Facebook" html?

Can I write my webpage completely in HTML5/CSS3/JS and put it on Facebook server?**

I know lot of people find this trivial but, **I need only to add a new page to already existing webpage**. *What should I do?*

Comment: There is not such thing as “Facebook HTML”. And no, you don’t put your app on Facebook’s servers. Please do some research into the basics of apps on Facebook!

Comment: Ok, I did, I still need to know FBML, so there is something like Facebook HTML, although it is not proprietary to Facebook it differs from HTML5 in a way it adds/removes some standard attributes, so please next time don't think you know everything only because you are rude!

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference.

Thing is, Facebook include your application inside an `iframe`. There's no "put on facebook server" thing. You host your application on your own server, facebook will just include it inside an iframe and give you access to an API.

If you were referring to `xfbml`, that thing have been deprecated for a long time. Also note, a lot of making app on facebook articles out there are spammy bullshit and incredibly out of date. Only refer to the official documentation and stack overflow answers if you need help.

Please read the doc here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

The basics points you should understand to get started are the SDKs, the Graph API, the Open Graph and the login.

Comment: I need only to add new page to already existing webpage. Thank you for your help, but I don't need external webpage that is connected to a Facebook account.